# Can I scroll to new lines using mouse wheel inside git diff?

Tags: git, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 default terminal (it's GNOME I believe?)

The problem I'm facing is that when I use `git diff` command to inspect my local changes I can scroll up/down using the mouse wheel, but no new lines are showing up when I get to the bottom (so I can see only one page of changes). In order to go to the next lines I can use space or up/down arrows of the keyboard, but can I somehow make this with the mouse wheel?

BTW If I use the `less` command it works as expected -> scrolling down goes to new lines.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to **@edwinksl**'s answer I managed to find a solution to the problem.

So by default git uses `LESS` as a pager and I believe the default arguments are `FRSX`.

On git 1.8+ you can remove options with `less -+<option>`, in my case I need to remove the `X` option so:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager 'less -+X'
```

but as **@pcworld** mention this can cause problems with diffs that fit on a single page, thus:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager 'less -+FX'
```

fixed the scrolling issue for me.

Comment: I needed to add `-+F` to the options of `less` or else output that fits on one screen is empty. Note that both options combined will pipe any output of git through a pager, even if it would fit on one screen. However there is a [wrapper script for less that calls less only if output exceeds screen size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329811/43920).
See [comments #10 and #11 on this Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=565699#10) and [this question on less](https://superuser.com/a/972232/199854) for more technical details.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows Terminal the answer didn't help me. Instead, I had to do the following:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager 'less --mouse'
```

Comment: @FelixDombek it worked for me on WSL ‍♂️

Comment: Works on Linux too. The minimum version to support `--mouse` is [549](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.549.html)

Comment: If anyone is here using https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy, then include `--mouse` after the `less --tabs=4 -RFX`. Given in readme file.

Answer (score 5):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183920/486919, one way to do this and preserve the diff highlighting is to use `git diff` without a pager:

```
git --no-pager diff
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this help me find the exact solution I was looking for -> enabling the mouse wheel scrolling. While removing the pager is a good work-around I prefer to start reading diffs from the beginning.

Comment: @Todor That is fair; I agree `--no-pager` is best for short diffs but not for long ones.